# How does ice affect the combustion systems of jet and piston aircraft engines?

Tags: jet-engine, piston-engine, icing

What are the effects of ice on a jet and piston aircraft engine? I've tried Google but I'm not satisfied with the results.

Comment: [Ice effects the _carburetor_](https://www.aopa.org/-/media/files/aopa/home/pilot-resources/asi/safety-briefs/sb09.pdf?la=en) of a piston engine, is that what you are asking about?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I'm not sure what you're asking, but [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12108/62) may answer the jet part, and [this one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/14033/62) the piston part. You might like to take the [tour] to learn more about how the site works. As it is, your question seems quite broad; if you can make it more precise and also tell us *why* Google didn't help you so far, that would help us to give you better answers.

Answer (score 2):

For piston engines, icing can obstruct the carburetor throat, reducing air to the engine.  Fuel injected engines are less prone to ice but it can accumulate on air intakes and engine air filters.  Carbureated engines have carburetor heat, which heats the induction air prior to entering the carburetor.  This eliminates or reduces icing at the expense of richening the mixture due to the decrease in air density due to heating.  Fuel injected engines usually offer an alternate air source for the engine which is less prone to icing than the primary but reduces the available manifold pressure for a given throttle setting in the process.  Alternate air intakes are sometimes also available to turbocharged engines to prevent compressor icing as well but may reduce the critical altitude of the turbo in the process.

Turbine engines can collect ice on the fan and/or compressor stators and rotors - al least the first or second stages of the LPC, increasing the risk of a compressor stall.  Icing can also accumulate on the engine inlet, reducing airflow to the engine.  Anti icing measures can include heating engine intakes using compressor bleed air to prevent ice accumulation